# File locations in binary file incorrect

Tags: c

I am reading a binary file into a set of external text files for post-processing. My code is as follows:

```
for(k = 0; k < 76; k++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 76; j++) {
        curr = curr + j + k*(dim - 76);
        sprintf(Filename, "%s_%d.txt", file,count);
        fp = fopen(Filename, "w");
        for(i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            fseek(qFile, (curr + i*dim*dim) * sizeof(float), SEEK_SET);
            fprintf(oFile, "%f\n", curr + i*dim*dim);
            fread(&temp, sizeof(float), 1 ,qFile);
            fprintf(fp, "%5.2f\n", temp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        count++;
    }
}
```

However, when I view the file pointed to by oFile, the beginning locations of each set of 256 values are not spaced by 1, but are as follows:

```
67024216
67024216
67024216
67024220
67024224
67024228
67024232
67024240
67024248
67024256
67024264
67024276
67024288
67024300
67024312
.
.
.
```

I cannot see why the spacing in the individual elements is in 4's, I know the size of the float is 4bytes, but the value that is being printed to file is not the number of bytes, but the multiple of the number of bytes.

Comment: I cannot realize what `dim` means, what type it has, what value it keeps, and why it is squared.

Comment: Also do you use expression of right type with `printf`? It requires `float` for `%f`.

Comment: @Vovanium No, `%f` is a double in `printf`. It's only a float in `scanf`.

Comment: Apologies @Vovanium. Dim is just the dimension of the binary file. It contains data in the form of a 3D cube. I am using C programming to get at the central 76-cubic part of the file. It is squared since I can then move to the data element directly behind the starting point on the 3D grid.

Comment: @Kevin, you're right, my mistake. (But anyway float is promoted to double)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code edited as follows produced the desirable result:

```
for(k=0;k<76;k++){
  curr = init+k*dim;
  for(j=0;j<76;j++){
curr = init+j+k*dim;
sprintf(Filename,"%s_%d.txt",file,count);
fp=fopen(Filename,"w");
for(i=0;i<256;i++){

  fseek(qFile,(curr+i*dim*dim)*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
  fprintf(oFile,"%lf\n",curr+i*dim*dim);
  fread(&temp,sizeof(float),1,qFile);

  fprintf(fp,"%5.2f\n",temp);
}
fclose(fp);
count++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Single-precision floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) don't work like integers.  They actually have *less* precision, because eight bits are used for the sign and exponent.  That leaves you with 24 bits.

And all of your numbers happen to fit into 24 bits.  Or, rather, they *would* if you lopped off the low two bits, which happen to always be zeroes (i.e., increasing by multiples of 4).

I don't know if it'll solve all of your problems, here, since I obviously don't know the details of the project.  But, if you change your `float` definitions to `double`, it should at least get you past this issue.

Comment: I changed the type of curr and dim to double-precision floating-point, but get the following output:   67024218, 67024219, 67024221, 67024224 - that is, the values are increasing by 1, 2, 3, 4, etc instead of 1 each time. Many thanks @John C.

Comment: But why are you using any sort of floating-point to store your file offset? It doesn't matter that the file data contains floats, the offsets are always integral types.

Comment: Oh I know that @AndrewMedico, however, I calculate the dimension of the 3D binary file in earlier C syntax:                              `fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);`
                                     `lSize = ftell (pFile);`
                                     `rewind (pFile);`

    `dim = pow(lSize/sizeof(float),1.0/3.0);`

Comment: That doesn't mean `dim` needs to be a float/double. You can convert the result from `pow` to an integral type.